# Extend elements in list of lists in Python

Tags: python, append, extend

I need to fill a list of lists with zeros up to a certain range. I am calculating the reduced profits for a period of infection (a_x). After the infection the profits have to be accounted for with zeros for all of my 3 systems. The planning horizon is 50 years, so I need to extend the elements in my list of lists (tilde_Pi_) to comprise of 50 elements in every sublist respectively.

```
# Parameters needed for the calculation
year = np.arange(50)
a_x = list(np.arange(5))
Y_ = [2, 8, 12]
C_ = [620, 2000, 4000]
p = 500
r = 0.03
RC_ = [1000, 5000, 10000]
m_ = [50, 30, 15]
ARC_ = [((RC_[i] * r) / (1 - (1+r) ** (-m_[i]))) for i in range(0, 3)]

# Relevant calculation
tilde_Y_ = [[(Y_[i] * 0.8 ** a_x[a]) for a in a_x] for i in range(0, 3)]
tilde_C_ = [[(C_[i] * 0.8 ** a_x[a]) for a in a_x] for i in range(0, 3)]
tilde_Pi_ = [[((p * tilde_Y_[i][a]) - tilde_C_[i][a] - ARC_[i])
              for a in a_x] for i in range(0, 3)]
```

I tried to write an .extend syntax but something is wrong

```
tilde_Pi_ = [tilde_Pi_[i].extend([0] * (len(year) - len(tilde_Pi_[i]))) 
             for i in range(0, 3)]
```

Does anyone have an idea how to extend the 3 lists in my list of lists (tilde_Pi_) to comprise of 50 elements respectively, the first 5 (len(a_x)) calculated as above, the remainder filled by zeros?

Comment: I think you give us too much information.

Comment: Im sorry, what should I have omitted?

Comment: @Kevin Anything that we do not need to know about what you are doing and why

Comment: So literally just write I want to extend the elements in a list of lists?

Comment: And give us a simple example and desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    tilde_Pi_[i].extend([0] * (len(year) - len(tilde_Pi_[i])))
```

The way to extend sublist is `listname[index].extend(new_element)`

Hope this helps!

Comment: perfect! did exactly what I was looking for. thank you very much!